# Split parameter from

Tags: c, scanf

I want to get substring from this string:

> "1,26,[1076168,'Stabaek','Brann','1.021',10,'08/07/2012 01:00','',0,0,1,6],,[[19,23,[]],[14148266,[1,0,1,0,5000,-0.50,19001],[-0.95,0.87]],[14166487,[1,0,1,0,2000,-0.25,19001],[-0.72,0.64]],[14148270,[5,0,5,0,2000,0.00,19001],[3.90,3.50,1.86]],[14166491,[1,0,1,0,3000,-0.75,19001],[0.80,-0.88]]],2"

So I called swscanf function like this!

```
swscanf( szTemp , L"%d,%d,[%d,\'%s\',\'%s\',\'%s\',%d,\'%s\',\'\',%d,%d,%d,%d],,[%s],%d" , &n1 , &n2 , &n3 , szA , szB , szT1 , &n4 , szTime , &n5 , &n6 , &n7 , &n8 , szThird , &n9);
```

The Result is:

```
n1: 1  
n2: 26  
n3: 1076168

szA: Stabaek','Brann','1.021',10,'08/07/2012 ( Incorrect)

szB: NULL
```

and the other parameter's value are also incorrect!

I can't know why this happen?

Please tell me the reason.

Comment: what is the expected value for szA, szB?

Comment: What is `szA` supposed to contain?

Comment: Edited the tags as this posted code is not C++, is not related to MFC or HTTP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the intention is to store `Stabaek` in `szA` then you need to exclude the `'` as it is not considered a delimiter for `%s` format. From the C standard for format `s`:

> Matches a sequence of non-white-space characters.

To exclude change `%s` to `%[^']`:

```
swscanf( szTemp , L"%d,%d,[%d,\'%[^']', ... ");
```

A few recommendations:

- place limits on the number of characters read into a `char[]` to avoid buffer overrun (32 in below example, remember to leave space for terminating null):

  ```
  swscanf( szTemp , L"%d,%d,[%d,\'%32[^']', ... ");
  ```
- check return value from `swscanf()`. It returns the number of successful assignments made. In the posted code, 14 assignments are being requested so the return value should be 14 (if all are required to be present);

  ```
  if (14 == swscanf(...))
  {
      /* All good. */
  }
  ```
- use the `%n` format specifier to determine to what point the input buffer was processed. I find this useful to check that the entire buffer was processed (if the entire buffer is expected to be processed):

  ```
  int pos;
  if (14 == swscanf(szTemp, "....%n", ...., &pos) &&
      pos == wcslen(szTemp))
  {
      /* All assignments made and processed entire buffer. */
  }
  ```

Comment: Oh, Excellent! szA value is Correct, But Please help me one more! I want to get szThird string correct! How can I do?

Comment: Must szThird = "[19,23,[]],[14148266,[1,0,1,0,5000,-0.50,19001],[-0.95,0.87]],[14166487,[1,0,1,0,2000,-0.25,19001],[-0.72,0.64]],[14148270,[5,0,5,0,2000,0.00,19001],[3.90,3.50,1.86]],[14166491,[1,0,1,0,3000,-0.75,19001],[0.80,-0.88]]"

Comment: But now, szThird = "[19,23,[]],[14148266,[1,0,1,0,5000,-0.50,19001],[-0.95,0.87]],[14166487,[1,0,1,0,2000,-0.25,19001],[-0.72,0.64]],[14148270,[5,0,5,0,2000,0.00,19001],[3.90,3.50,1.86]],[14166491,[1,0,1,0,3000,-0.75,19001],[0.80,-0.88]]],2

Comment: @bTagTiger, I don't know how to express that using `sscanf()` formats. Here is a possible solution that requires more that just `sscanf()`: http://ideone.com/6Wa61

Comment: @bTagTiger, yes I just chose not to in my example.